# Need to find the size of files using recursion

Tags: java

A method that has one File argument. If it is a directory, the method returns the total size (number of bytes) of all files below it. If the argument represents a file, the method just returns the size of that file. The return value should be of type `long` (which is a kind of integer with a larger range of values than `int`). To determine the size of a file represented by a File object, use the `length()` method of the File class (this method doesn't work for directories, just files).

Would really appreciate any help! Can't seen to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far. It's okay if it doesn't work, that's what SO is for. It will help people better see what you're missing and be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @FatalError it is just a homework question

Comment: freelancer.com and pay fortune for your home work.

Answer (score 1):

Given this is homework, I won't give you the answer straight off.

Recursion if a mechanism where a method calls itself. Obviously if a method does this indefinately you'll eventually get a stackoverflow exception, so you need some sort of exit condition where the method stops calling itself.

In your case the exit condition is when you encounter a file, so you'll have code that's something like this:

```
int size(file)
{
  if file represents a directory
  {

    loop over contents of the directory calling size method with each item and sum the return values

    return the sum

  }
  else file represents a file
  {

    return file size

  }
}
```

When a program like this runs, each invocation is being added to the stack, so in the case where you have the following file structure:

```
+ root
  + directory 1
    + file 1
    + file 2
  + file 3
```

Your stack would follow this pattern:

```
                                  size(file1)                           size(file2)
            -> size(directory) -> size(directory) -> size(directory) -> size(directory) -> size(directory) ->            -> size(file3) ->
size(root)     size(root)         size(root)         size(root)         size(root)         size(root)         size(root)    size(root)     size(root)
```

Hopefully that shows you the general approach, I'll leave for you to convert to Java.